# How to create multiple files with different names

Tags: php, json

How to create multiple files with different names with json.
I have this code but it saves only one file. I would like to be able to save multiple files with different names

code here:

```
       <?php
$json= json_encode($_POST['donnee'],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

$donnee=str_replace("\\","",$json);
$donnee=str_replace("\"{","",$donnee);
$donnee=str_replace("}\"","",$donnee);
$donnee=str_replace('""type','"type',$donnee);
$donnee=str_replace(']"',']',$donnee);


$donnee ='{'.$donnee.'}';
$fp=fopen('data.json','w');
fwrite($fp,$donnee);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. Are there multiple files listed in the incoming data? Give an example of the contents of `$_POST['donnee']` please. It's also unclear why you're encoding that as JSON and then doing lots of string manipulation on it. You seem to have gone down a very weird rabbit hole which almost certainly isn't necessary, and I suspect stems from some sort of misunderstanding of the incoming data format. Please clarify the data being supplied, and the exact end result you want.

Answer (score -2):

```
    $json= json_encode($_POST['donnee'],JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    
    $donnee=str_replace("\\","",$json);
    $donnee=str_replace("\"{","",$donnee);
    $donnee=str_replace("}\"","",$donnee);
    $donnee=str_replace('""type','"type',$donnee);
    $donnee=str_replace(']"',']',$donnee);
    
    
    $donnee ='{'.$donnee.'}';

    #create random filename
    $rand = rand(0, 1000); 
    $file = '.json';
    $filename = $rand.$file;
    $fp=fopen($filename,'w');
    fwrite($fp,$donnee);
    fclose($fp);
    echo "My data is in $filename";
```

Comment: Code-only answers are not useful. Provide an explanation of what you've done and why you think it solves the problem. Personally I think this answer is premature anyway because we don't have a clear definition yet of precisely what the OP wants. You're assuming they want a randomly generated filename, but I see nothing in the requirements about that. The question is about creating multiple files with different names, not about renaming a single file.

Comment: its clear that the OP wants his data in different files, his code rewrites the existing file. By this code snippet he can find his mistake and make the code work for his needs.

Comment: Yes but it's not clear if they actually want to create multiple files based on the content of the $_POST data. They don't necessarily want a random filename.

Comment: And even if you're right about the requirement, it's still downvoted for complete lack of any meaningful explanation. You should edit the answer.